# Is it possible to create if statement dynamically based on JSON in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, json, parsing

I would like to know that is there any approach to create "if" statements dynamically in C or C++ based on JSON.

For example, I have following JSON input

```
Rule1
    {
      "ifstatement1": {
        "condition1": 0,
        "condition2": "down"
      },
      "actionstatement1": {
        "val1": 235959,
        "val2": "yes",
        "val3": 5,
        "val4": 0,
        "val5": "increse",
        "val6": 1
      }
    }

Rule2
    {
      "ifstatement2": {
        "condition1": 2,
        "condition2": "up",
        "condition3": 10
      },
      "actionstatement2": {
        "val1": 1223,
        "val2": "no",
        "val3": 5
      }
    }
```

Based on above JSON input, I need to create if statements dynamically using C or C++. Have to parse above json data and treat this as actual if-else statements in C or C++.

whatever comes like "ifstatement1", should be converted to condition check, if this check is true then have to apply values present in "actionstatement1".

Number of ifstatements and action-statements can vary dynamically.

Is there any specific approach in C or C++ for evaluating json data as parameters dynamically ?

This is like a Rules that we are giving in JSON format. This rules should be stored when the program starts and it will be checked in particular period of time with the current values and stored values. if any condition matches, then apply values of that condition.

Please share if any better approach is available.

Comment: what kind of condition is this: `"condition1": 0, "condition2": "down"`? Because if you want to generate `if (0 && "down")` you won't go very far with your end product

Comment: It would be possible to parse the input and generate output with the desired if statements (you could provide more info and examples on how they should look...). However the program doing that can never then execute those statements, simply because C and C++ (please decide what you are asking about) both are compiled languages.

Comment: I don't understand your question: `if` is dynamic by nature: the condition will be evaluated at runtime. Do you want to do an if-else statement based on values in JSON file specified by a given key?

Comment: @papagaga, this is sample conditions. if (condition1 == 0 && !strcmp(condition2, "down") ) then perform an action. condition1 values can be 0,1,2... and based on those values actions will vary.

Comment: @Yunnosch, I will be passing multiple Rules in JSON format to a program. It should store all combinations of Rules. While program is running, have to check the occurrence of this rules and apply the respective values. As you said, compiled languages, agreed that we cannot create statements dynamically. I will pass this Rules only on starting of the program and I can write condition checks if we know exactly how conditions and respective values. I don't have total number of conditions. So, is there any better approach available without changing the code frequently if number of condition varies.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi, Yes. You got my view. Is it possible to do like that in C or C++ ? if not, which is best programming language to achieve this. It would be fine, if possible with combining C and another programming language.

Comment: "which is the best programming language to achieve this?": not the kind of question you'll find the answer to on stack-overflow (broad question, opinion-based answers). That said I'd take a look to lua if I were you (simple dynamic language with a lot of mature bindings to C/C++ available, frequently used for games).

Comment: My better approach to this problem is NOT to use JSON. If I understand you correctly, you are trying to implement a simple scripting language expressed in JSON. JSON is a very nice data serialization language, but it is not very useful for program logic. (It is basicaly JavaScript with the program logic stripped out, and only keeping the data structures). I would recommend you to pick one of the existing scripting languages. Personally I am a fan of scheme, but other popular choices are Python, Lua or Javascript. (Javascript will fit natuarally with JSON)

Answer (score 2):

So if you are thinking of creating `if` statement inside your `C++` code on the fly or after you compiled your code, the answer is you cannot do that. You can create parser that will have `if` statement ready for you. Remember C and C++ are compiled languages meaning what you put in code it is compiled to 0s and 1s and when you run it, those 0s and 1s are in memory loaded for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the condition you want to achieve and also make a decision about using C or C++ otherwise your question is too general.

Also yours does not look like a proper JSON: what is `Rule1`?Is it a Key? Then it should be something like `{"Rule1" :{...}}` and the inner structure should be same for example `"ifstatement"` instead of `"ifstatement1"` and `"ifstatement2"`, `"actionstatemen"` instead of `"actionstatement1"` `"actionstatement2"`

I will assume your JSON, which is not a JOSN for how you posted, has the form:

```json
[
    {
      "id" : "Rule1",
      "ifstatement": {
          "condition1": 0,
          "condition2": "down"
      },
      "actionstatement": {
        "val1": 235959,
        "val2": "yes",
        "val3": 5,
        "val4": 0,
        "val5": "increse",
        "val6": 1

    },
    {
      "id": "Rule2",
      "ifstatement": {
        "condition1": 2,
        "condition2": "up",
        "condition3": 10
      },
      "actionstatement": {
        "val1": 1223,
        "val2": "no",
        "val3": 5
      }
    }
]
```

There are different libraries that allows that in C++. One of them is [`JSONcpp`](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) (I downloaded the source code but maybe if you are on Unix/Linux there is a binary version you can install.

The code I used to read it is something like:

```
Json::Value root;
std::string dataFileName = "yourPath/filename.json"
if( access( dataFileName.c_str(), F_OK ) != -1 )
{
  std::ifstream file(dataFileName);
  file >> root;// file exists

  for (Json::Value::ArrayIndex i = 0; i != root.size(); i++)
  {
    for (Json::Value::ArrayIndex j = 0; j != root[i]["ifstatement"].size(); j++)
    {

      (root[i]["ifstatement"][j] );
      ...
    }

  }
}
```

So basically `root` represents all your file and the type `Json::Value::ArrayIndex j` allows to iterate through your JSON file that, for how I have rewritten its most external structure is an array. Then you can access the fields as:
`root[0]` equivalent to your original RUle1 and then specify the key: for example `root[0]["ifstatement"]`. If you have to convert a value to integer from the JSON file you should use the method `asInt()` or `asFloat()` for float.

Being your question too general I cannot help you further :(

Answer (score 0):

As others have said from both the comments and User [Gox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5550963/gox)'s answer; you can not dynamically create `if statements` on the fly or dynamically speaking.

However, after reading your comment or reply to another:

> This is sample conditions. `if (condition1 == 0 && !strcmp(condition2, "down") )` then perform an action. condition1 values can be 0,1,2... and based on those values actions will vary.

This gives me a little more information about what you are trying to achieve. As others have stated you would probably have to write a parser to have `if statements` ready for you, but if you take your input from your `JSON` and create a relationship tree for example:

```
Initial Condition:   Determining Condition:        Action To Perform:  
condition1 == 0:     !strcmp(condition2, "down")   perform desired action
condition1 == 0:     next condition                perform desired action
...
condition1 == 1:     ...                           ...
...
condition1 == 2:     ...                           ...
```

You should be able to create some kind of key structure such as using a `std::multimap` or something similar to build your table.